# Ionic 4 HTTP error

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework

Hola estoy intentanto hacer una peticion get con HTTP pero no me entra en data.data
me dice undefined, me puede ayudar? Gracias!

Falta el codigo de la api no la publico.

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';


@NgModule({
imports: [
IonicModule,
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab1Page }])
],
 declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {
 constructor(private http: HTTP) {
this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040,us&appid=', {}, {})
.then(data => {

  console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
  console.log(data.headers);

})
.catch(error => {

  console.log(error.status);
  console.log(error.error); // error message as string
  console.log(error.headers);

});
 }
}
```

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El json me devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: inspecciona el navegador (Network) o as la prueba con el postman y revisa que en verdad tu petición devuelva una respuesta y la estructura del json es lo que esperas

Comment: Si, arriba lo puedes ver.

Comment: solo imprime data y mira la estructura correcta del json y creale un interface y tipa tu peticion, ya que data no tiene .data ni .status ni .headers, data viene a hacer todo ese json del viewer

Comment: Pero esta entrando dentro del error

Comment: veo que la api esta en la nube puedes compartirme exactamente la url de peticion ylas variable que envia

Comment: Si perdona. Esta es la api: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040,us&appid=28374da3c0b0372b6020a42e6c645092

Comment: a tu peticion le falta http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040,us&appid=fala setear el dato aca

Comment: No veo que le falta, perdon

Comment: falta us&appid=  no le estas seteando el valor 28374da3c0b0372b6020a42e6c645092

Comment: this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040,us&appid=28374da3c0b0372b6020a42e6c645092', {}, {})
.then(data => {

  console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
  console.log(data.headers);

})
.catch(error => {

  console.log(error.status);
  console.log(error.error); // error message as string
  console.log(error.headers);

});

Comment: Si que lo estoy haciendo, arriba he puesto: Falta el codigo de la api no la publico. Porque no lo queria poner, pero esta puesta en mi codigo

Comment: mira le agrege a mi modulo de un proyecto angular y trae normal la data pruebalo asi tambien lo use en mi app y trae la data import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Pero yo he mirado en la documentacion de ionic y he encontrado esto: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http#usage

Comment: tambien uso ionic y no hay problema en usarlo como el ejemplo que te envie

Comment: Pues no entiendo a mi no me sale ese ejemplo

Comment: bueno no se que mas pueda hacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira le agrege a mi modulo de un proyecto angular y trae normal la data, pruebalo asi 
tambien lo use en mi app y trae la data crea un providers

```
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

 @Injectable()
 export class ApiProvider{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public demostracion(): Observable<MiInterface>{
        return this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=94040,us&appid=28374da3c0b0372b6020a42e6c645092').catch((error) => Observable.throw('Error', error));
    }  
   }

   export interface MiInterface{
     cod?: string,
     message?: number,
     cnt?: number,
     list: any[],
     city:any
   }
```

en el componente donde lo uses lo inyectas en el contructor y tambien declaras como providers y lo llamas asi..

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
 ...
 providers: [ApiProvider]
})
export class demo{

 constructor(private apiProvider: ApiProvider) { }

 ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.apiProvider.demostracion().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('ENTRE esta la data', data)
   }, error => {
      console.log('error', error);
  });
 }


}
```

donde data tendra el tipo MiInterface y podras poner data.cod y podras obtener la ayuda de teclado si tienes configurado correctamente tu IDE

espero haberte ayudado agrega la importaciones necesarias ...